# Access result type of a function template parameter in the template?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, function-object

Given the following template:

```
template<class T>
class Container
{
private:

    boost::function<T> f;
};
```

... and its instantiation, perhaps as follows:

```
    Container<bool(int, int)> myContainer;
```

, is there a way to access the return type of the function description and compile conditionally against it?  For example, if the caller specifies his function returns bool (as in the above case), I want to include a function that returns a value.  If he specifies that the function is void, I don't want this function to be included.  For example:

```
// Include if the return type of T is void
template<class T1, class T2>
void DoSomething(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    f(t1, t2);
}

// Include if the return type of T is not void
template<class T1, class T2>
***whatever the return type is*** DoSomething(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    return f(t1, t2);
}
```

I'm guessing there is a solution here, but it probably involves some horrendously obfuscated template meta-programming solution.  I know Gregor Cantor went mad contemplating infinity... template meta-programming kind-of has the same effect on me :p.

Thanks for any thoughts you might have.

RobinsonT

Edit:  Obviously this can be solved by implementing a different class (perhaps derived from a common base), one called VoidContainer and the other called ReturnsContainer (or similar).  However this seems a little unsatisfactory to me...

Comment: I think Cantor rather went mad because he didn't find much understanding from his contemporaries (and for personal reasons only known to himself). You have the support of SO community.

Comment: Yes. But I think either I will go mad trying to understand, or the SO community will go mad trying to explain.  Either way someone is going to be sat on a chair with his pants on his head and a pencil up each nostril.

Comment: And it's Georg Cantor, not Gregor Cantor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you actually need to specialize for void return type. A void function is allowed to return the "result" of another void function for exactly this scenario.

```
void foo() { }
void bar() { return foo(); } //this is OK

int main()
{
    bar();
}
```

So your only problem would be how to determine the return type.

It appears that `boost::function` has a typedef for `result_type` (see http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/functionN.html)

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>


template<class T>
class Container
{
public:
    typedef typename boost::function<T>::result_type result_type;
private:

    boost::function<T> f;
};

Container<bool(int, int)>::result_type r = true;
```

---

Edit:
Now that you know what the `result_type` is, and you do need to distinguish between void/non-void results, you can employ `enable_if` and `disable_if`. The only complication is that those only work with function templates, so a non-template `foo` calls a templated `do_foo`.

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

template<class T>
class Container
{
public:
    typedef typename boost::function<T>::result_type result_type;


    result_type foo() 
    {
        return do_foo<result_type>();
        //note that this still works because you can return the void result! :)
    }
private:
    //use this if the result_type is void
    template <class U>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<U, void>, U >::type do_foo()
    {
        std::puts("for void");
    }

    //else
    template <class U>
    typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_same<U, void>, U>::type do_foo()
    {
        std::puts("other");
        return U();
    }
private:

    boost::function<T> f;
};


int main()
{
    Container<void()> a;
    a.foo();

    Container<int()> b;
    b.foo();
}
```

Comment: For void return type, it's true you don't need to specialise in the case I gave above.  But suppose I have a collection of boost::function<f> and that I want to store the result of each call to f() [0..n] into a collection, assuming that DoSomething returns a collection now rather than ::result_type.  In the void case a collection won't compile (std::list<void>) and, indeed, wouldn't make any sense even if it did.  That's why I wanted something that would discriminate between the two cases and not try to instantiate the non-void function if the return type of T is void.

Comment: @robinsont: Edited answer to show how `enable_if` could be used to distinguish between the two cases.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`boost::function_traits`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html), which has a `result_type` typedef.

Comment: What would that look like?  I did play with is_void and enable_if but couldn't get anything to compile using them.  Can I write is_void<T> in the above example, where T is function prototype bool(int, int)?  Or do I have to pass in the result_type trait to the is_void function?  Function traits in this case is a on T.  So do I write function_traits<T>::result_type?

Comment: @robinsont:  `is_void<T>` is false if `T` is a function type, so, yes, you'd basically need to use `boost::is_void<typename boost::function_traits<T>::result_type>::value` (or something close to that; I don't have Boost on this lappy to test, and C++0x doesn't have `function_traits`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to so, maybe you are making things more complicated than necessary. If the `f` you call in the `void` case is a void function itself, you can just keep the `return`.

Explicitly returning a "void value" is ok:

```
void f() {
}

void g() {
   return f();
}
```